# metalearning algorithm issue in Super Learner Algorithm in h2o-ai

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, h2o, ensemble-learning

i had succeeded in implementing a super-learner in H2o-ai and spark
but as per the second step super-learner utilizes a meta learning algorithm

Super-learner algorithm

1Set up the ensemble.
1.a Specify a list of L base algorithms (with a specific set of model parameters).
1.b Specify a metalearning algorithm

the complete algorithm is available at http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html

So for the same meta learning algorithm i had utilized a function

```
val metaLearningModel= new H2ODeepLearning()(hc, spark.sqlContext)
```

And it seems that it is using an inbuilt package from h2o-ai so i want to know which meta learning algorithm it is using as default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default metalearner algorithm is noted on the Stacked Ensemble User Guide page that you've linked above.  There is also more information available at the [`metalearner_algorithm`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/metalearner_algorithm.html) page.

The default metalearner is:

> "AUTO" (GLM with non negative weights, and if validation_frame is present, lambda_search is set to True; may change over time). This is the default.